# How to select all non null items from a field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

How can i select all the items from a table, let say books(tablename) where category(field) is not null.

I have used where = operator ?? is there a way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select * from books
where category is not null
```

Comparing something to `null` will result in `unknown`. That is why you have to use the `is` operator with `null`s.

Comment: i have used = operator actualy

Comment: You have to use is not NULL . You cannot use' =' here.

Comment: actualy i've to use for one such condition

Comment: in short i need to fetch all category results